# How to display Object array in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

This is my code which I am using but when I am trying to print `dataArray` object, then data is not show in `JTable`. Which model properties of table to print Object array values can used and how?

```
public class ShowAddressForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Object data[][];
    Object dataArray[][];
    int count = 0;
    String st;

    public ShowAddressForm(String fname , String str) {
        super(fname);
        st = str;
        initComponents();

        fillTable();
    }

    public void fillTable()
    {
int count = 0;
        String str;

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\JavaPrograms\\Contact Management System\\InputFiles\\AddressFile"));

            while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                count++;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        Object id;
        Object name;

        data = new Object[count][7];

        int i = 0 , j = 0 , m;

        try
        {
            BufferedReader buffrea = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\JavaPrograms\\Contact Management System\\InputFiles\\AddressFile"));

            while((str = buffrea.readLine()) != null)
            {
                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str , "*");

                int n = token.countTokens();

                id = token.nextElement();
                name = token.nextElement();

                String strNameLow = name.toString().toLowerCase();
                String strNameUpp = name.toString().toUpperCase();

                if(strNameLow.startsWith(st.toLowerCase()) || strNameUpp.startsWith(st.toUpperCase()))
                {
                    data[i][0] = id;
                    data[i][1] = name;

                    for(j = 2 ; j < n ; j++)
                    {
                        data[i][j] = token.nextElement();
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }

            buffrea.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error : " + ioe.toString());
        }

        dataArray = new Object[i][7];
        for(int a = 0 ; a < i ; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0 ; b < 7 ; b++)
            {
                dataArray[a][b] = data[a][b];
            }
        }

        //Here is the code to print dataArray object which i used but it is not working, when i am run my program it is print "[Ljava.lang.Object;@1cc2e30" in table's first cell[0][0] position  

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.data_table.getModel();
        model.addRow(dataArray);
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Use some hard coded data to replace the text file. 2) *"..in java in Netbeans"* The solutionis to be found in Java code, not the IDE, so 'Netbeans' is irrelevant. 3) `catch (Exception e) { }` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: You never add the JTable/JScrollPane to the frame

Answer (score 1):

I filled data in a JTable like this. You might want to give it a try adapting it to your code. Variable and stuff are in spanish, just replace them with what you need. In my case it's a table with 4 columns representing a date, a score, duration and max viewers.

```
    private void fillJTable(){
        //creating data to add into the JTable. Here you might want to import your proper data from elsewhere
        Date date = new Date();

        UserReplay rep1 = new UserReplay(date, 12, 13,14);
        UserReplay rep2 = new UserReplay(date, 2,34,5);

        ArrayList<UserReplay> usuaris = new ArrayList<>();
        usuaris.add(rep1);
        usuaris.add(rep2);
//----Filling Jtable------
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) view.getTable().getModel();
        model.addColumn("Fecha");
        model.addColumn("Puntuación");
        model.addColumn("Tiempo de duración");
        model.addColumn("Pico máximo de espectadores");

        for (int i = 0; i < usuaris.size(); i++){
            Vector<Date> fecha = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(usuaris.get(i).getDate()));
            Vector<Integer> puntuacion = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(usuaris.get(i).getPuntuacion()));
            Vector<Integer> tiempo = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(usuaris.get(i).getTiempo()));
            Vector<Integer> espectadors = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(usuaris.get(i).getTiempo()));

            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            row.addElement(fecha.get(0));
            row.addElement(puntuacion.get(0));
            row.addElement(tiempo.get(0));
            row.addElement(espectadors.get(0));
            model.addRow(row);
        }

    }
```